# How to use user input to obtain a data.frame from my environment in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Hi i am trying to figure out how to use the user input i generate to call an existing table in R shiny. Each user input options is the name of a table, i want to use this input to then call the selected table.

```
ui=fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId="location",label="Please Choose location", choices=c("Dublin"="Dublin","Cork"="Cork","Galway"="Galway","Belfast"="Belfast")),
  tableOutput("table")
)
server=function(input, output){

  input=reactive(input$location)
  output$table<-renderTable(input())

}
```

However this just creates a new table with one row containing the user input.

Comment: This is quite elementary lad, I suggest you go through the documentation on shiny website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `get()` to obtain the `data.frame`. Also, note that `input` is not a good name for a reactive variable, since it is already defined, therefore I renamed in to `inputx`. In this case, you could even do without the reactive and simply use `output$table<-renderTable({get(input$location)})`

Hope this helps!

```
Dublin=Head(mtcars,5)
Cork=head(mtcars,10)
Galway=head(mtcars,15)
Belfast=head(mtcars,2)

ui=fluidPage( 
  selectInput(inputId="location",label="Please Choose location", 
              choices=c("Dublin"="Dublin","Cork"="Cork","Galway"="Galway","Belfast"="Belfast")), 
  tableOutput("table") ) 

server=function(input, output){

  inputx=reactive({get(input$location)}) 
  output$table<-renderTable(inputx())

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

---

The cleanest solution would probably be to store your dataframes in a list, and subset from that list as follows:

```
Dublin=Head(mtcars,5)
Cork=head(mtcars,10)
Galway=head(mtcars,15)
Belfast=head(mtcars,2)

mylist = list(Dublin=Dublin,Cork=Cork,Galway=Galway,Belfast=Belfast)

ui=fluidPage( 
  selectInput(inputId="location",label="Please Choose location", 
              choices=c("Dublin"="Dublin","Cork"="Cork","Galway"="Galway","Belfast"="Belfast")), 
  tableOutput("table") ) 

server=function(input, output){
  output$table<-renderTable(mylist[input$location])
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, I know it was a basic question but could not find the answer anywhere, once again thank you

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!