# Apply a function within a loop

Tags: r, function, loops, vector

Let's say we have 4 vectors, each one of them corresponding to values of some indicator in year i (i is between 11 and 14):

```
vector_11 <- c(1,2,3,4)
vector_12 <- c(5,6,7,8)
vector_13 <- c(9,10,11,12)
vector_14 <- c(13,14,15,16)
```

... and the following function :

```
myfunction <- function (vect){
res <- sum(vect)
return(res)
}
```

I'd like to "select" the vector according to the value of another variable : year. And then, apply myfunction() to the corresponding vector.

I've tried to do this with a loop, and the function paste() but the problem is that R reads it as a character argument :

```
year <- 14
for (i in 11:14){
 if (year==i){
  vect <- myfunction(paste("vector_",i,sep=''))
 }
}
```

Comment: replace everything with `sum(get(paste0("vector_",year)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `get()` to fetch the object from the environment. So this should work:

```
vector_11 <- c(1,2,3,4)
vector_12 <- c(5,6,7,8)
vector_13 <- c(9,10,11,12)
vector_14 <- c(13,14,15,16)

myfunction <- function (vect){
  res <- sum(vect)
  return(res)
}

year <- 14
for (i in 11:14){
  if (year==i){
    vect <- myfunction(get(paste("vector_",i,sep='')))
  }
}
```

However, it may be easier/better practice to just put the vectors in a named list, and subset from that list, e.g.:

```
mylist = list('11' = c(1,2,3,4),
'12'=  c(5,6,7,8),
'13'=  c(9,10,11,12),
'14'=  c(13,14,15,16))

myfunction <- function (vect){
  res <- sum(vect)
  return(res)
}

year <- 14
for (i in 11:14){
  if (year==i){
    vect <- myfunction(mylist[[as.character(year)]])
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! :) Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same method to "input" objects in R Shiny ?

Comment: Yes definitely. I recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549945/how-to-use-user-input-to-obtain-a-data-frame-from-my-environment-in-shiny/48550215#48550215). Does that help you?

Comment: You can fetch input object by string with `input[[x]]` where `x` is your string, is that what you mean? If not, maybe consider opening a new question on Stack Overflow with your desired behavior :)

Comment: Well, not really. I've juste asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788042/select-different-columns-in-rendertable/48788180#48788180) where I explain better what I'm trying to do.