# Select different columns in renderTable

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe that is updated each time the user changes the year, let's call it mydata.

In output, I'd like to have a table with the possibility to select columns to show, but I'd like the "choices" argument (in the checkboxGroupInput) to be different according the year.

Short part of my current code :

Ui :

```
sliderInput("year","Choose the year",min=2013,max=2018,value=2017,step=1,sep=""),
conditionalPanel(condition="input.year==2013",
             checkboxGroupInput("show_vars13", "Choose variables to show:",colnames13, 
                                 selected=c(var1,var2))
),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.year==2014",
             checkboxGroupInput("show_vars14","Choose variables to show:",colnames14,
                                selected=c(c(var1,var2))
),
conditionalPanel(condition="input.year==2015",
             checkboxGroupInput("show_vars15","Choose variables to show:",colnames15,
                                selected=c(var1,var2))
),
conditionalPanel(condition="input.year==2016",
             checkboxGroupInput("show_vars16","Choose variables to show:",colnames16,
                                selected=c(var1,var2))
),
conditionalPanel(condition="input.year==2017",
             checkboxGroupInput("show_vars17","Choose variables to show:",colnames17,
                                selected=c(var1,var2))
),

tableOutput("data")
```

server :

```
output$data <- renderTable({

  year <- as.numeric(substr(input$year,3,4))

  for (i in 13:17){
    if (year==i){
      show_vars <- get(paste("input$show_vars",i,sep=''))
  }
}

  return(mydata[, show_vars, drop = FALSE])
})
```

This code doesn't work. R Shiny returns "object 'input$show_vars17' not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
show_vars <-input[[paste0("show_vars",i)]]
```

Comment: Thanks again :P very useful

Answer (score 0):

in

`show_vars <- get(paste("input$show_vars",i,sep=''))` ,

`"input$show_vars"` is just a string ..

if you want to refer to the variable, remove quotes, and write :

`show_vars <- get(paste(input$show_vars,i,sep=''))`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry .. I didn't pay attention to your `i` .. Try  this :  `get(input$eval(paste("show_vars",i), sep = '')`

Comment: Still doesn't work... :/ This time, I got "attempt to apply non function"

Comment: Adding to the correct answer of @Florian, you can also get rid of `i` if you call your varables `show_vars2014` instead of `show_vars14` and just write `input[[paste0("show_vars",input$year,sep='')]]`and get rid of `for` and`if `